# Im using the following code for event listener in an audio player tag for a webpage to a specific link,you can review my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, event-listener

this is the html audio player tag , but the event listener is no working as i'm coding for a user to land in a specific page on playing the audio for few seconds,Whats wrong with my code,Do i need to change the code?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(“audio”).on(“play”, function() {
    window.location.href = “http: //landingpage.com”
  })
})
```

```html
<audio controls="controls">
  <source  src="audio.mp3">
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: Note that your quotes are invalid for use in JS, you need to use `"` or `'`, not `“` and `”`

Comment: Aside from what Rory mentioned, which is probably the core reason, did you check for errors in your console?

Comment: Besides the problems mention by Rory, there is also a space btw `http:` and  `//` on the address. should be `http://`

Comment: @j08691 I didnt check it in console,Instead i tried it on a webpage that is not functioning correctly

Comment: @j08691 even this code is not working
 <script type=’text/javascript’>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(“audio”).on(“play”, function() {

window.location.href = “http: //landingpage.com”

})

})

</script>

Comment: What.Errors.Are.You.Getting.In.The.Browser's.Console? Let's start with the simple things like did you load jQuery successfully?

Comment: @j08691 the html tag for the browser is working perfectly but i'm getting the following error "Your browser does not support jquery audio element".Is there something wrong with my event listener code?

Comment: What browser are you using and is that the *exact* error you get? The word "jquery" is in the error?

Comment: the word "jquery is not in the error", but when i load  webpage on a server audio is played well but the problem is that it does not redirect to the link mentioned in an event listener thread.What shall i do?

Comment: I'm using opera browser but can i use this function $("audio").on("play", function (me)

Comment: @j08691 why event listener is not working?